# multiple streams in one GPU device

Tags: multithreading, cuda, gpu

I have a multi-threaded program which supposed to run on 6 GPU devices.
I want to open on each device 6 streams to reuse during the lifetime of my program (36 in total).

I'm using cudaStreamCreate() cublasCreate() cublasSetStream() to create each stream and handle.
I also use a GPU memory monitor to see the memory usage for each handle.
However, when I look at the GPU memory usage on each device, it grow only on the first stream creation, and doesn't change in the rest of the streams I create.

As far as I know there isn't any limitation on the amount of streams I want to use.
But I can't figure out why the memory usage of the handles and the streams don't show up on the GPU memory usage.

Comment: Creation of the first stream on each device is probably initializing the CUDA context for that device.  That will involve a significant/noticeable amount of memory usage.  The additional stream creations on each device don't involve this context initialization, so the additional memory usage is tiny (or zero) by comparison.

Answer (score 2):

All the streams you create are residing within a single context on a given device, so there is no context related overhead from creating additional streams after the first one. The streams themselves are lightweight and are (mostly) a host side scheduler abstraction. As you have observed, they don't in themselves consume much (if any) device memory.